Torch sparse using enviroment CUDA version instead of torch's version
I'm trying to run a Python script in a cluster that requires the following:
torch==1.7.1
torch-sparse==0.6.8
The problem is that when I install both of these, torch comes with a cuda version of 10.2 and torch-sparse uses the available version in the cluster, which is 11, so it gives the following error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/g.pocas/GraphGONet/scripts/GraphGONet.py", line 6, in <module>
    from torch_geometric.data import DataLoader
  File "/home/g.pocas/GraphGONet/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch_geometric/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    import torch_geometric.nn
  File "/home/g.pocas/GraphGONet/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch_geometric/nn/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from .data_parallel import DataParallel
  File "/home/g.pocas/GraphGONet/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch_geometric/nn/data_parallel.py", line 5, in <module>
    from torch_geometric.data import Batch
  File "/home/g.pocas/GraphGONet/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch_geometric/data/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .data import Data
  File "/home/g.pocas/GraphGONet/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch_geometric/data/data.py", line 8, in <module>
    from torch_sparse import coalesce, SparseTensor
  File "/home/g.pocas/GraphGONet/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch_sparse/__init__.py", line 27, in <module>
    raise RuntimeError(
RuntimeError: Detected that PyTorch and torch_sparse were compiled with different CUDA versions. PyTorch has CUDA version 10.2 and torch_sparse has CUDA version 11.2. Please reinstall the torch_sparse that matches your PyTorch install.

I have tried installing torch without cuda, and the version of torch sparse should be compatible with torch 1.7.1 since I installed it directly from the wheel they provide, so I'm really not sure what can be causing this.

The version you require could be installed via pip with:
pip install torch-sparse -f https://data.pyg.org/whl/torch-1.7.1+cu102.html
